# JavaFX custom controls created with a Builder and binding expressions

Tags: spring, javafx

I’m using Spring together with JavaFx. To use spring bean as a custom control I need to use BuilderFactory and a Builder to get a bean from the context. Otherwice I don't have an application context

**Parent.java**

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ParentControl extends VBox {

  @Autowired
  ControlFXMLLoader controlFXMLLoader;

  @Value("classpath:/parent.fxml")
  private Resource fxml;

  @PostConstruct
  void load() throws IOException {
    controlFXMLLoader.load(fxml.getURL(), this);
  }

  public ParentControl() {
    //no application context
  }

  public LocalDate getDate() {
    return LocalDate.now();
  }
}
```

**BeanBuilderFactory.java**

```
@Component
public class BeanBuilderFactory implements BuilderFactory {
  private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BeanBuilderFactory.class);

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

  public BeanBuilderFactory() {

  }

  private JavaFXBuilderFactory defaultBuilderFactory = new JavaFXBuilderFactory();

  @Override
  public Builder<?> getBuilder(Class<?> type) {
    try {
      String[] beanNames = context.getBeanNamesForType(type);
      if (beanNames.length == 1) {
        return new Builder<Object>() {
          @Override
          public Object build() {
            return context.getBean(beanNames[0]);
          }
        };
      } else {
        return defaultBuilderFactory.getBuilder(type);
      }
    } catch (BeansException e) {
      return defaultBuilderFactory.getBuilder(type);
    }
  }
}
```

And then I user this BuilderFactory to load fxml for a custom control

**ControlFXMLLoader.java**

```
@Component
public class ControlFXMLLoader {

  private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ControlFXMLLoader.class);

  @Autowired
  protected ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

  @Autowired
  protected BeanBuilderFactory beanBuilderFactory;

  public Object load(URL fxmlUrl, Parent root, Object controller) throws IOException {
    logger.debug("load");
    javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader loader = new javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl);
    loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
    loader.setBuilderFactory(beanBuilderFactory);
    loader.setRoot(root);
    loader.setController(controller);
    return loader.load();
  }

  public Object load(URL fxmlUrl, Parent root) throws IOException {
    return load(fxmlUrl, root, root);
  }
}
```

Now I have a child custom control

**ChildControl.java**

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ChildControl extends VBox {

  public ChildControl() {
  }

  @Autowired
  ControlFXMLLoader controlFXMLLoader;

  @Value("classpath:/child.fxml")
  private Resource fxml;

  @PostConstruct
  void load() throws IOException {
    controlFXMLLoader.load(fxml.getURL(), this);
  }

  ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>();

  public LocalDate getDate() {
    return date.get();
  }

  public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date.set(date);
  }

  public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {
    return date;
  }

  @FXML
  protected void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("The button was clicked! " + date.get().toString());
  }
}
```

And want to assign the date to the child from parent fxml

**parent.fxml**

```
<fx:root type="com.example.javafx.ParentControl" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <ChildControl date="${controller.date}"/>
</fx:root>
```

**child.fxml**

```
<fx:root type="com.example.javafx.ChildControl" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <TextField fx:id="textField"/>
    <Button text="Click Me" onAction="#doSomething"/>
</fx:root>
```

The problem is that FXMLLoader doesn’t not allow to use Binding Expression together with a Builder. I got "Cannot bind to builder property." exception.
Below is the part of the code from **FXMLLoader.java** and the very last **if** that causes the problem.

Is there some other solution?

**FXMLLoader.java**

```
public void processPropertyAttribute(Attribute attribute) throws IOException {
    String value = attribute.value;
    if (isBindingExpression(value)) {
        // Resolve the expression
        Expression expression;

        if (attribute.sourceType != null) {
            throw constructLoadException("Cannot bind to static property.");
        }

        if (!isTyped()) {
            throw constructLoadException("Cannot bind to untyped object.");
        }

        // TODO We may want to identify binding properties in processAttribute()
        // and apply them after build() has been called
        if (this.value instanceof Builder) {
            throw constructLoadException("Cannot bind to builder property.");
        }
```

Comment: I tried my best to describe the problem. Is it better now?

Comment: thanks, looks good to me :) Now the experts in interaction of spring and fxml can jump in, I think.